# Xcode "TODO" comment is not rendered bold in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax-highlighting

I just wonder, why in both Xcode11 and Xcode12 `TODO` comment isn't bold in Swift? 
While it's bold in ObjectiveC/C++.

---

**Swift**:

[image]

**Objc**:

[image]

---

Is it some Swift code style consideration, or a bug?

I guess that the main purpose of doing such annotations is to show them in `Jump Bar`, but seeing bold "TODO" while skimming through the code is also important, I assume.

Comment: I assume they have changed this on purpose and that it is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a leading `#` or `**` at the beginning and the end to make the comments to make it bold.

```
///#TODO: do stuff
///or
///**TODO: do stuff**
```

Comment: But triple / is meant for documentation so while this gives you a bold text it is slightly confusing

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which **todo2** will be **bold**:

```
    /*:     
  __todo2__.
 */
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH2-SW1

Comment: This is not a one liner like the original TODO and it doesn't work in a project code file, only in a playground, so it is of limited use.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for attention. I just was pushing how the bold style can be written in Swift

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space before TODO after //, and a colon after TODO in order to let Xcode know your annotation.

e.g.

```
// TODO: something to do
```